# ¿Como desactivar clave primaria en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

estoy intentando hacer un registro en la tabla ForDefParEgr de una base de datos ORACLE, la cuestión es que contiene dos campos, uno como "CODPAREGR" y otro "NOMPAREGR", y esta tabla no contiene el campo ID, OJO: no puedo agregarselo, ya que esta tabla tiene relación a una aplicación de escritorio y funciona perfectamente, el objetivo es sistematizar esta app pero en WEB, lo estoy haciendo en Laravel, primero me dio un problema con el timestamp() y coloque en el modelo de esta tabla lo siguiente:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Con eso me funcionó y no medio problemas al insertar, pero ahora el problema es con el campo ID. me dice que el numero de posición es inválido:

**Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: invalid number Position : 92 Statement**

También quiero aclarar que este campo necesita tener guiones "-" es decir, los datos son numéricos y necesitan ser divididos por guiones, maximo 4 guiones necesita, si inserto en el formulario sin guiones me funciona perfectamente, pero con guiones me aloja el error mostrado anteriormente, Alguna idea?

NOTA: No estoy trabajando con migraciones, por lo que no puedo quitar ese campo y nadamas, las tablas ya están definidas en oracle y debo adaptar la aplicación a como está en oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu modelo, agrega estas propiedades:

```
protected $primaryKey = null;
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: Gracias bro me sirvió, tenia la variable $primaryKey como el campo incrementable, y al desactivarlo toma el campo como cualquier string y es capaz de recibir cualquier dato varchar, eso solucionó.